# Adonis 5 "make:migration command not found" any idea?

Tags: typescript, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

i read the basic documentation of new Adonis Js5, i make a new api serve and i compile the code with "node ace serve --watch" or "node ace build --watch" and always is the same "make:migration command not found" any idea for fix?

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you validate the answer for your question or add more details to fix your issue? Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

**The `@adonisjs/lucid` dependency is missing (lucid provider)**

According to the official documentation

> The data layer of the framework is powered by Lucid and the package
> must be installed separately.

#### Setup Lucid

*Official documentation : https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/introduction*

run (install dependence) :

```sh
> npm i @adonisjs/lucid
# or
> yarn add @adonisjs/lucid
```

and (setup lucid) :

```sh
> node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid
```

and build one time application (`node ace build`)

Answer (score 0):

After Adonis 5 going live, the [database documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/database/introduction) has new installation instructions in the Introduction section, with this configuration step:

```
node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid
```